# Not able to use docker login --password-stdin

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I would like to push a built docker image in the central docker hub in an automatic build process. To be able to do that, I need to login first before doing the push then.

The relevant section of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is the following:

```
docker-deploy:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - echo $HUB_PW | docker login -u $HUB_USER --password-stdin
  after_script:
    - docker logout
  script:
    - docker push <mytag>:$CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

I get the following error in Gitlab CI

```
$ echo $HUB_PW | docker login -u $HUB_USER --password-stdin
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

The relevant environment variables `$HUB_PW` and `$HUB_USER` are set correctly.

I have tried to do the same in a linux bash, with docker available, with the same result.

However, I am able to login into docker interactive.

```
docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: <myusername>
Password: 
Login Succeeded
```

When I do a logout, I get

```
docker logout
Removing login credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

There is no way to do an interactive login in an automatic build. And I don't understand the difference in the hubs URL, depending on using the interactive login and the one with the password included.

Has anyone any idea how to get this setup working?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would help but maybe start with quoting password to avoid some problems with some special chars so I would write `echo "$HUB_PW" | docker login -u "$HUB_USER" --password-stdin`

Comment: @JakubBujny Thanks for the tip, but I have a not so dangerous password, and it makes no difference if I quote the env variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem because of $USERNAME contained `$` character. By using the name with escape character directly in .gitlab-ci.yml for docker login
`example: robot\$myname`

gitlab connected to docker hub as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab variables with `$` in them can be escaped with a double dollar sign e.g. `robot$$pusher`.

`\$` didn't work for me on enterprise edition 13.6.7-ee, but as far as I can tell double dollar escape syntax has been around since at least community edition 11.0.3